# Qt 4 QAtomicInt: How to load() and store()?

Tags: c++, qt, atomic

I have the following code which works for Qt 5:

```
QAtomicInt myAtomicInt;
myAtomicInt.load();
myAtomicInt.store(123);
```

Now I would like to write the same code for Qt 4. However, the Qt 4 version of QAtomicInt does not have member functions load() and store(). How to proceed? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QAtomicInt::load()` gets the value using relaxed memory ordering, so `fetchAndAddRelaxed(0)` would do the same in Qt 4.

`QAtomicInt::store(int)` stores the value using relaxed memory ordering, so `fetchAndStoreRelaxed(int)` would do the same in Qt 4.